# How can I improve my heat tolerance, including increasing the amount that I sweat?

Tags: heat-tolerance

I grew up in Lousiana and couldn't do anything physical from about May to thru Sept.

I live in southwest virginia and it's not nearly as humid and I still get overheadt mountain biking in 80F weather.

I'm trying to improve my heat tolerance. I don't sweat much. I've tried Endurolyte tablets (Hammer Strength), which help. I think I sweat a bit more when taking them.

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

- I also use HEED (also from Hammer, and I've used Gatoraid but I think HEED works a bit better).
- Endurolyte electrolyte tablets from Hammer.
- Evaporative cooling "collar" that goes about 4" down my back, shoulders and chest.

But even with all of the above I don't think I sweat enough and get overheated fairly easily. And If I don't stop, I'll get a really bad migraine. (The Endurolyes allow me to stop when a migraine is impending and not get the migraine. Without the Endurolytes, the migraine would be ineveitable once I "sensed" it was near)

Comment: I know this is increase and that is decrease, but the basic question of altering sweat rate is answered there.

Answer (score 0):

There are some very common things that sadly cause heat intolerance in very many people. They may not become aware of it until they experience truly warm climates, so many don't even know that they have it.

**Caffeine** often increases heart rate and metabolism. These are things that may cause your temperature to rise over longer periods of time, which may in turn cause heat intolerance. And of course, many people who work out take dietary supplements containing caffeine, so don't think purely about coffee here.

**Anxiety** is also a known cause.

**Menopause**... Well, maybe not in your case, but women have a tendency of experiencing periods of extreme heat during menopause. And please note that I am using the word heat to refer to temperature, and not to sexual appetite (i.e. *being in heat*).

**Don't do drugs!** Appetite-suppressing drugs like amphetamines can also cause heat intolerance.

**Hyperthyroidism** will more often than not be accompanied by heat intolerance, and is caused by

- eating foods that contain iodine
- Graves disease
- thyroid inflammation (certain medications, viral infections and pregnancy can cause this)
- testicular or ovarian cancer
- taking too much thyroid hormone

In many countries, if you have a documented case of a disease which is related to heat intolerance, you would be able to deduct things like air conditioning systems as a medical expense if your doctor prescribes it.

But barring all those worst case scenaria, and looking to more practical options, **drink plenty, and I mean *plenty* of water!** Profuse sweating *will* dehydrate you over time. Wear light cotton clothing (it breathes).

If you do suspect that there is an underlying medical cause for your issues, you absolutely should visit a doctor about it if you haven't already done so.